# naming classes practices in R

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to OO programming and would like to have some advice on how I develop and use my classes.

Currently I make all my class instances as an "inheritance" parameter to the underlying class structure if there so exists. E.g if an object is originally of type list I would do

```
class(x) <- c("my class", "list")
return(x)
```

My logic is that this will not impair the use of the outputted object with other packages and base functions that rely on it as an *list* object. Is this practice "correct" (I do not have an CS background)? And is there a better way to proceed in these matters?

Comment: I've gotten by in R without ever needing to define a class, but if you're keen to do it, you might want to check out hadley's OO guide if you haven't already: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html

Comment: you don't need to do that with lists, but you can also do `class(x) <- c(class(x), 'my_class)'` as a more general solution. I would advise not using spaces, however

Comment: @rawr, is there a typo in class(x) <- c(class(x), 'my_class')? And where would you not advice to use spaces?

Comment: ^^ I would second that classes in R aren't particularly useful, and I've gone several years without using them. The way classes are used in R is not very similar to classes in other OO languages.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with doing it that way, so long as that's your intended behavior; *to treat `x` as `my_class` whenever possible and as a `list` only when a specific method for `my_class` isn't available`.*

Hopefully this example will illustrate:

```
df1 = df = data.frame(ID = 1:5, Value = rnorm(5))
class(df) <- c(class(df), "my_class")
class(df1) = rev(class(df))
x = letters[1:5]
class(x) <- "my_class"
```

Define a specific method of summary for `my_class`:

```
summary.my_class <- function(x) print(names(x))
```

See what happens:

```
> summary(df)
       ID        Value       
 Min.   :1   Min.   :-2.980  
 1st Qu.:2   1st Qu.:-1.697  
 Median :3   Median :-1.478  
 Mean   :3   Mean   :-1.118  
 3rd Qu.:4   3rd Qu.:-1.306  
 Max.   :5   Max.   : 1.873  
> summary(df1)
[1] "ID"    "Value"
> summary(x)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Assigning classes that way is fine, you just have to be intentional about the order of assignment, and be aware of which functions you use have specific methods.